# Why does tomcat returns status code 200 on OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, out-of-memory

I am running spring application under tomcat, sometimes OutOfMemoryError occurs in it. Tomcat always returns 200 status code for responses with this error, content of these responses is empty.

Other exceptions handled correctly, how can I fix this issue? I want to get status 500 on this exception.

Comment: Do you have any custom filters installed?

Comment: Yes, many, but these filters does not make any special handling for this type of exception.

Comment: If you sure then only debuggin will help :(

Comment: Try to set breakpoint to the end of your controller method

Comment: Method throws this OutOfMemoryError exception, something wrong happens in spring framework (or Tomcat) after handling this error, so it returns status code 200.

Comment: The exception is handled somewhere and there it is replaced with 200